# Can I map CAPSLOCK to AltGr with AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

I am running Windows 7 and would like to use the <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> key as <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, because I don't use it anyway and shortcuts like <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> (`{`on the German keyboard) hurt the fingers.

I tried the following AutoHotkey script, because AltGr does not have its own symbol, but it seems like you cannot map a single key to two combined keys:

```
Capslock::LControl & RAlt
```

Am I doing it wrong or is this just not possible with AutoHotkey? If not, are there other tools that make it possible?

Comment: Have you tried to Send it? ```Capslock::Send {LControl}{RAlt}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggestion in the comment may work...

```
Capslock::Send {LControl}{RAlt}
```

And you may or may not need to add a second hotkey for release if things get stuck.

```
Capslock::Send {LControl down}{RAlt down}
Capslock Up::Send {LControl Up}{RAlt up}
```

I can't test this on my keyboard.

See also [this](https://superuser.com/questions/980748/autohotkey-eu-keyboard-how-to-remap-lctrl-while-keeping-altgr/981098#981098) somewhat similar/related post.

Comment: The second example doesn't work (tested in Win10). it will leave you completely stuck you at altgr